# Laravel 5 - Only Owner (creator) can edit/delete/view Entry

Tags: php, authentication, filter, laravel-5, middleware

I'm new to `Laravel` and have a little Question.

I want to accomplish that just the Creator/Owner of a post can edit/view/delete it.

Each Post belongs to a User and each User can have multiple Posts (1-to-Many relationship). That part works like a charm.

To be more specific, if one of these routes is called:

```
GET mydomain.com/posts/{id} (show)

GET mydomain.com/posts/{id}/edit (edit)

PUT mydomain.com/posts/{id} (update)

DELETE mydomain.com/posts/{id} (destroy)
```

the application should check if the currently authenticated user's id matches the posts user_id field.

As far as I know this is not possible with a middleware because the middleware does not have access to the current Post-Object and I can't pass a paramenter to it.

Currently I was able to accomplish my goal with a filter (I use Route-Model binding).

```
Route::filter('isOwnerOfPost', function() {
 if(Route::input('posts')->user_id !==  \Auth::id()) {
    abort(403);
 };
});

Route::get('posts', 'PostController@index');
Route::group(['before' => 'isOwnerOfPost'], function(){
 Route::resource('posts', 'PostController', ['except' => ['index', 'create', 'store']]);
});
```

But this solution seems a bit messy to me. I would have to create a new filter for every Model and I can't use resourceful routing (at least not completely).

Is there a better way to accomplish such a behavior?

Comment: One should definitely check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733709/laravel-5-middleware-owner#answer-29734984). It has entire relevant middleware developed and explained fantastically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it with a middleware. The following code only works if route model binding for the parameter is 'active'.

I don't really know if this is the right way to do this, but it seems to work...

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $requestParameters = $request->route()->parameters();

    foreach ($requestParameters as $requestParameter) {
        // Loop through route parameters
        if (gettype($requestParameter) === "object") {
            // Route Model Binding is active for this parameter
            if (isset($requestParameter->user_id)) {
                // Model has an owner (column user_id is set)
                $owner = $requestParameter->user_id;

                if ($owner !== Auth::id()) {
                    // Authenticated user is the not owner
                    abort(403);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `Gate` or built in `can` middleware for this purpose according to the official documentations (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization)