# Laravel 5 Middleware "Owner"?

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, laravel-5, middleware

I'm having a trouble with creating the "owner" middleware.

For example, I have a `Articles` and `User`model associated with `user_id` key.

I want to add the "owner" middleware to the `ArticlesController`, so the only owner of that article can edit, update and delete it.

I've been searching for this issue for a while, but never found the code, which would work. 
Some of them tried to make it work with Form Requests, but I'm interested in using Middleware.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Create middleware:

```
php artisan make:middleware OwnerMiddleware
```

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Article;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class OwnerMiddleware
{
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $articleId = $request->segments()[1];
        $article = Article::findOrFail($articleId);

        if ($article->user_id !== $this->auth->getUser()->id) {
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

2. Add it to `app\Http\Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'owner' => 'App\Http\Middleware\OwnerMiddleware',
];
```

3. Use middleware in your routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['owner']], function() {
    // your route
});
```

Comment: Do you have to create a new `handle()` for each Model?

Comment: This looks ok but it is dependant on the URL structure no? Is there any way to just get the model in the $request and compare the user_id?

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you could use route and [middleware parameters](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#middleware-parameters), it has some advantages:

- Even if the request structure changes your middleware would still work
- The middleware is reusable for differents resources
- You can use it inside controllers

Here’s the middleware (`app/Http/Middleware/AbortIfNotOwner.php`):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AbortIfNotOwner
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string    $resourceName
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $resourceName)
    {
        $resourceId = $request->route()->parameter($resourceName);

        $user_id = \DB::table($resourceName)->find($resourceId)->user_id;

        if ($request->user()->id != $user_id) {
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Inside `app\Http\Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
     'owner' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AbortIfNotOwner',
];
```

Inside your route file (`app/Http/routes.php`):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['owner:articles']], function() {
    // your route
});
```

And optionally call it in the controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('owner:articles', ['only' => ['edit', 'update']]);
}
```

Comment: very clever! this should be default in laravel

Comment: the problem is it ends up querying for it twice, you might be better implementing it after the model binding, or on the model in the updating method.

Comment: What do you mean? The `construct` and `routes` approaches are complementary, you don’t need to do both.

Comment: You are fetching the owner from the db on every web request, making an unnecessary n+1 bug with this middleware. Get the authenticated user from the request object, middlewares are already passing this data around, no need to hit the db one extra time for every darn request.

Comment: “Get the authenticated user from the request object”. Isn’t that exactly what I do?: `$request->user()->id`.

Comment: @Gluten Please, update the answer with example URL. That will shed some more light on usage and allow users understand it better and faster.

Comment: The issue is `\DB::table($resourceName)->find($resourceId)->user_id`, which queries the model, retrieves it (along with all columns unnecessarily included), assumes `user_id` exists on the model (it could have a convention-breaking name), then just discards the model... when the request gets to the controller, the controller itself then has to reacquire the model, requiring two queries when only one should be necessary.